# How to print 2 int(s) but not add them?

Tags: java, string, printing, int, addition

I know this seems like a stupid question (so excuse me). Basically this is what I want to do:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

System.out.print(a+b);
```

this will give me 8, but is there a way other than putting an empty string inbetween for it to print 5 and 3 (and not by converting the int to a string)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you want to print `53`, or do you want something between the `5` and the `3`? And please add a tag to indicate what language this is (Java?)

Answer (score 11):

The print method will simply convert its argument to a string and write out the result. Therefore, if you want to display the two numbers concatenated, you will need to do this yourself by converting them to a string (either explicitly, or using "" as you've already mentioned).

If you want to avoid building the string yourself, you'd probably need to use the printf() method:

```
System.out.printf("%d%d", a, b);
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
System.out.print(a+""+b)
```

or

```
System.out.print(a+" "+b)
```

if you want a space between them

Answer (score 2):

Java will always execute an arithmetic operator. To avoid this behavior, you need to convert the numbers to string.

This should work for you:

```
System.out.println("" + a + b);
```

Because of the empty string at the beginning, Java is going to interpret + as a concatenation operator and joins the values of your variables with the empty string.

Comment: That will give you `53`, which is not likely to be what you want.

Comment: @KeithThompson Judging by the somewhat vague question it looks like it's what the author asks for.

Answer (score 1):

1. User explicit string conversion (not so elegant solution):

```
    System.out.print(new Integer(a).toString()+b);
```

2. Use sequential calls to System.out.print (no new line will be added):

```
    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.print(b);
```

3. Use java.lang.StringBuilder:

```
    import java.lang.StringBuilder;
    ...
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(a);
    sb.append(b);
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: All of which are unnecessarily complex. The author also asks for a way by not converting it to a string.

Comment: I find the `StringBuilder` approach overly comples. But option 2., calling `print()` twice, should be easy for everyone including beginners to understand.

Comment: @Jite There’s no avoiding conversion to `String` implicitly or explicitly. All you can print in the end is chars and strings of chars. All the other answers convert to string too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the parameter inside the println method into a string 
    literal ,then java compiler would recognize it as a string and will not add 
    two integers.

```
    System.out.println(a+""+b);
```

**or use format method**

```
    System.out.format("%d%d",a,b);
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.